# how to install tcl in linux system

Tags: linux, tcl

I am using a Tcl script to change the poller password through spawning the telnet command. 
I have done this with the script below, and tested it on a Windows machine after installing `ActiveTcl8.5.13.0.296436-win32-ix86-threaded`

```tcl
spawn telnet $serNumber $pNumber
#flush stdout
expect ">"

send "Clients\r"
expect ">"

send "1\r"
expect ">"

send "Pollers\r"
expect ">"
```

Now I want to run same script in a Linux machine, but as I am new to Linux systems, can anybody help me that how to install tcl in linux system and get executed the same script there?

Any help is a great for me. Please provide any useful links.

Comment: Isn't Tcl inbuilt in linux?

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using, or are you rolling your own? This affects what answer is best for you...

Comment: @Jerry - tcl is in-built for linux? i am new to linux system. if it's in-built. so what is command to execute script there. i mean in windows i am running like `tclsh filename.tcl`

Comment: I have a Linux Mint where I have run tcl scripts using `tclsh filename.tcl` in the bash. I don't have other versions of Linux though.

Comment: Tcl is often preinstalled. Otherwise use your favorite package manager to install tcl and expect.

Comment: @DonalFellows - using Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 6)
Linux version 2.6.9-67.EL

Answer (score 8):

You're in luck. RHEL 4 has expect in its repositories. You can simply install it with `yum`:

```
yum install expect
```

and it should install expect and all its dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

You're not using Tcl, you're using `expect`, which is a separate program which just happens to use Tcl. To install it, do

```
apt-get install expect
```

Note that the above command is a guess as you did not tell us which Linux-based OS you're using ("Linux" is not an OS, it's just a kernel).

If you have no one to ask which system you're running, post the results of running the following commands:

```
uname -a
lsb_release -a
cat /etc/issue
```

so we could try to make an educated guess.

Answer (score 3):

To install Tcl on Linux (I'm using RedHat), you can do

```
yum install tcl
```

And you will get the most recent version of tcl.

Answer (score 2):

on ubuntu:

```
 sudo apt-get install tcl
```